# Allow $title argument with HTML code

Tags: hyperlink, laravel, laravel-4, html-entities

I work with Laravel 4.
I want to use the [HTML::linkAction](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Html.HtmlBuilder.html) to provide a link embedded in an image.

The method's prototype is :

`linkRoute( string $name, string $title = null, array $parameters = array(), array $attributes = array() )`

Then I use the image method to get my `<img></img>` code :

`HTML::linkAction('contact@index', HTML::image('images/contact.png', 'contact'));`

It works almost fine. The problem is that the `<img></img>` code is formatted like htmlspecialchars() do.

Is there a way to allow HTML code in parameters, or to deactivate the htmlspecialchars fonctionality ? Or maybe it's a bad practice ?

Thanks,
Raphaël N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass HTML to `linkAction()`, because it internally calls:

```
$this->entities()
```

Here is the code for `link()`, wich is used by `linkAction()`:

```
public function link($url, $title = null, $attributes = array(), $secure = null)
{
    $url = $this->url->to($url, array(), $secure);

    if (is_null($title) or $title === false) $title = $url;

    return '<a href="'.$url.'"'.$this->attributes($attributes).'>'.$this->entities($title).'</a>';
}
```

And there is no options to do it differently.

So if you need to pass an image, you'll have to write HTML for that particular link.

Comment: I'm surprised that the Laravel's HTML object does not provide a way to do it.

Thanks,